# Recommended tool to automate complicated build procedure

Tags: makefile

I am developing an OS for embedded devices that runs bytecode. Basically, a micro JVM.
In the process of doing so, I am able to compile and run Java applications to bytecode(ish) and flash that on, for instance, an Atmega1284P.

Now I've added support for C applications: I compile and process it using several tools and with some manual editing I eventually get bytecode that runs on my OS.
The process is very cumbersome and heavy and I would like to automate it.

Currently, I am using makefiles for automatic compilation and flashing of the Java applications & OS to devices.

All steps, roughly, for a C application are as follows and consist of consecutive manual steps:

(1) Use Docker to run a Linux container with lljvm that compiles a .c file to a .class file (see also https://github.com/davidar/lljvm/tree/master)

(2) convert this c.class file to a jasmin file (https://github.com/davidar/jasmin) using the ClassFileAnalyzer tool (http://classfileanalyzer.javaseiten.de/)

(3) manually edit this jasmin file in a text editor by replacing/adjusting some strings

(4) convert the modified jasmin file to a .class file again using jasmin

(5) put this .class file in a folder where the rest of my makefiles (the ones that already make and deploy the OS and class files from Java apps) can take over.

Current options seem to be just keep using makefiles but this is a bit unwieldly (I already have 5 different makefiles and this would further extend that chain). I've also read a bit about scons. In essence, I'm wondering which are some recommended tools or a good approach for complicated builds.

Comment: The chief problem seems to be step 3, which in turn requires steps 2 and 4. I would first replace step 3 with an automated process working on .class files.

Comment: First thing I would suggest is "get rid of steps 2-3-4, work on .class files". Depending on which modifications you need, this may or may not be the easiest solution. Alternatively, replacing/adjusting strings seems like a job for [sed](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-basics-of-using-the-sed-stream-editor-to-manipulate-text-in-linux), since you already have a linux command line available. To my mind, a master Makefile still seems like the best option you  have

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. So no significant preference to upgrading/sidegrading to tools like Scons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this may help a bit, but the question as such could probably be a subject for a heated discussion without much helpful results.

As pointed out in the comments by others, you really need to automate the steps starting with your `.c` file to the point you can integrated it with the rest of your system.

There is generally nothing wrong with make and you would not win too much by switching to SCons. You'd get more ways to express what you want to do. Among other things meaning that if you wanted to write that automation directly inside the build system and its rules, you could also use Python and not only shell (should that be of a concern though, you could just as well call that Python code from make). But the essence of target, prerequisite, recipe is still there. And with that need for writing necessary automation for those `.c` to integration steps.

If you really wanted to look into alternative options. [bazel](https://bazel.build/) might be of interest to you. The downside being the initial effort to write the necessary rules to fit your needs could be costly. And depending on size of your project, might just be too much. On the other hand once done with that, it'd be very easy to use (apply those rules on growing code base) and you could also ditch the container and rely on its more lightweight sand-boxing and external rules to get the tools and bits you need for your build... all with a single system for build description.